# printing characters stored in variables

Tags: c

I can't get my function to print characters i have initialised and declared.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

  char letter1 ="i";
  char letter2 ="n";
  char letter3 ="C";

  printf ("Programming %c%c %c\n", letter1, letter2, letter3);


  return 0;
}
```

I want it to display

```
     "Programming in C"
```

using

```
    printf ("Programming %c%c %c\n", letter1, letter2, letter3);
```

I get the following error

```
main.c:4:8: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion 
initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'char [2]' [-Wint- 
conversion]
                    char letter1 ="i";
                                             ^
```

I haven't learn about pointers or anything yet, I'm used to simpler languages that just work. I am trying to go through an edX course but I find the quality to be poor and the pacing tedious.

Would be happy if you could help me out here and recommend me better resources for learning C

thanks

Comment: `"i"` is a *string* literal, you want *character* literals, which use a single quote `'i'`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant

Comment: I didn't even know there was a difference, thanks it works now <3

Comment: Or change `char` to `char *` and then do `printf ("Programming %c%c %c\n", *letter1, *letter2, *letter3);` (otherwise character literals use ***single-quotes*** while string literals use ***double-quotes***)

Answer (score 0):

```
 char letter1 ="i";
```

Unfortunately, `"i"` is a string. Use `'i'` for characters or `"i"[0]` if you really want to.

If your compiler didn't give you a warning, it's either a terrible compiler or you don't have appropriate warnings turned on. If you got a warning and you ignored it ...